# CLANG: How to obtain the init value of a static data member in a class

Tags: clang, clang++

Given a class with a static constexpr to const char*:

struct S
{
  static constexpr const char *str = "123";
  ...
};

While parsing it under clang AST, would I be able to get the string expr "123" from FieldDecl class through GetInClassInitializer()? I think I will get some kind of pointer, but would that point to some area with "123"?  If not, what should be the correct clang API call to get the value?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I was thinking too much for the use of "const" in the data member def.  I had concern the string "123" may not be available during parse time.  It turns out it is available and the access is pretty simple.  Suppose "d" is pointing at the member def of "str" above", a function fragment to return the initialized string can be something as follow:

```
...
if ( VarDecl *vard = dyn_cast<VarDecl>(d) ) {
   if ( vard->isStaticDataMember() ) {
       Expr *expr = vard->getInit();
       Expr *constExpr = expr->IgnoreImpCasts();
       if ( StringLiteral *str = dyn_cast<StringLiteral>(constExpr) )
          return str->getString().str();
   }
}
```